# Regex to get the number between word and char

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the number from string between '_text' word and '_' char.
I tried my regex on regex101 page and there it's working but in my code I didn't get anything.

```js
const s = 'line0_text4_89yf9sd9afg977f8gds9g9fdg'
const regexToGetNumber = '/_text(.*?)_/gm';
const result = s.match(regexToGetNumber);  // and it's null
```

In that case I expect the 4.

Comment: TLDR: Remove single quotes and the `gm` flags, use `const regexToGetNumber = /_text(.*?)_/;`. Since the result is in Group 1, access it: `s.match(regexToGetNumber)?.[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you quoted the expression. The `String` prototype does not have a `match` method. It needs to be a regex literal or `RegExp` object.

You can use a positive look-behind `(?<=_text)` and a positive look-ahead `(?=_)` and wrap the expression `[^_]*` (zero or more non-underscores).

You can extract the first match with destructuring the result array.

```js
const str = 'line0_text4_89yf9sd9afg977f8gds9g9fdg';
const regexToGetNumber = /(?<=_text)[^_]*(?=_)/gm;
const [value] = str.match(regexToGetNumber) ?? [];

console.log(value); // '4'
```

If you have a regex string, you need to call the `RegExp` constructor:

```js
const str = 'line0_text4_89yf9sd9afg977f8gds9g9fdg';
const regexToGetNumber = new RegExp('(?<=_text)[^_]*(?=_)', 'gm');
const [value] = str.match(regexToGetNumber) ?? [];

console.log(value); // '4'
```